# facebook instant article sdk step by step in core php in localhost

Tags: facebook-instant-articles

How to implement facebook instant article sdk for php with localhost.I am using graph api to submit my article in facebook but i want to change my html to facebook instant article html automatically.

Comment: Please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), show what you have tried so far to help contributors help you.

Answer (score 0):

The only option for integration you will have for localhost dev environment setup will be the [GraphAPI ingestion](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instant-articles/api).

And still, you will need to claim URL to get content ingested to that particular page.

Example: `yourdomain.com`

You can create a `dev.yourdomain.com` and claim this just for your development environment.
Then you can create Instant Articles using the [SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instant-articles/sdk) and use as your canonical URL the `dev.yourdomain.com`.

Example:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" prefix="op: http://media.facebook.com/op#">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <!-- URL of the web version of this article -->
    <link rel="canonical" href="http://dev.yourdomain.com/article.html">
    <meta property="op:markup_version" content="v1.0">
  </head>
  <body>
    <article>
      <header>
        <!-- The title and subtitle shown in your Instant Article -->
        <h1>Article Title</h1>
        <h2>Article Subtitle</h2>

        <!-- The date and time when your article was originally published -->
        <time class="op-published" datetime="2014-11-11T04:44:16Z">November 11th, 4:44 PM</time>

        <!-- The date and time when your article was last updated -->
        <time class="op-modified" dateTime="2014-12-11T04:44:16Z">December 11th, 4:44 PM</time>

        <!-- The authors of your article -->
        <address>
          <a rel="facebook" href="http://facebook.com/brandon.diamond">Brandon Diamond</a>
          Brandon is a avid zombie hunter.
        </address>
        <address>
          <a>TR Vishwanath</a>
          Vish is a scholar and a gentleman.
        </address>

        <!-- The cover image shown inside your article --> 
        <!-- TODO: Change the URL to a live image from your website -->    
        <figure>
          <img src="http://example.com/path/to/img.jpg" />
          <figcaption>This image is amazing</figcaption>
        </figure>   

        <!-- A kicker for your article --> 
        <h3 class="op-kicker">
          This is a kicker
        </h3>        

      </header>

      <!-- Article body goes here -->

      <!-- Body text for your article -->
      <p> Article content </p> 

      <!-- A video within your article -->
      <!-- TODO: Change the URL to a live video from your website -->    
      <figure>
        <video>
          <source src="http://example.com/path/to/video.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
        </video>
      </figure>

      <!-- An ad within your article -->
      <!-- TODO: Change the URL to a live ad from your website -->    
      <figure class="op-ad">
        <iframe src="https://www.example.com/ss;adtype=banner320x50" height="60" width="320"></iframe>
      </figure>

      <!-- Analytics code for your article -->
      <figure class="op-tracker">
          <iframe src="" hidden></iframe>
      </figure>

      <footer>
        <!-- Credits for your article -->
        <aside>Acknowledgements</aside>

        <!-- Copyright details for your article -->
        <small>Legal notes</small>
      </footer>
    </article>
  </body>
</html>
```